# WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 10.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.191

Tags: java, javafx, scene

I know that this problem was here but the solution didn't help me.

```
public class Main extends Application{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    launch (args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("/NOWY/Main2.fxml"));
    Pane Pane = loader.load();
    Scene scene = new Scene(Pane);

}

}
```

I changed sth in this place (image) but it is still wrong.

[image]

Comment: Probably just need to change the header at the top of the `FXML` file.

Comment: @Mirko Ebert  I do sth that and I have errors: [link]https://imgur.com/a/qd0mo3M